# How can I fix my image paths in a .htaccess rewrite?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've made a rewrite rule as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index.php)|(index.php)|\.(gif|jpe?g|png)|(/public/)|(/forum/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?qs=$1
```

When one goes to say, `www.example.com/a/b`, everything is fine, except images.

Images are linked as relative paths in my script, and they are located in `www.example.com/images`, but server is trying to load images from `www.example.com/a/b/images`.

Is there a way to solve this problem by editing my RewriteRule? This would be an optimal soloution, because it's very hard to change all the image paths in my script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for your first line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index.php)|(/images)|(images)|(/forum/)
```